# gitignore propagating exlusions to lower levels into directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a in `gitignore`

```
*
!.*
```

and I would expect that I see all the subdirectories of `.*` but indeed git sees only the ones where the subdirectory starts again with `.`. For example, I see `.java/.userPrerfs/.user.lock..`, because both subdirectory start with `.`, but I do not see `.conf/ario` or `.java/fonts/`.

How does one limit the exclusion of `*` just to apply to the top level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include the path at the same level as your `.gitignore` file

```
!./.*
```

Answer (score 0):

`!.*` since you did not "map" directory its not working for you.

The `.` stands for the current directory so you are only ignoring files in the specified directory.

use this:

```
*
!**/.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I did further experiment and found, for the more elaborate need, that

```
/*
!/.*
/.*/*
!/.config/*
/.config/*/*
!/.config/*/*.conf
```

works for me to find the `.conf` files inside the `.config` directory.

The approach for me to find the solution was to write line by line and for each line to test what is included and what not. It seems that `/` can be used for the present directory (or for `~`). Perhaps there is an explanation.

I appreciated the two suggestions which helped me understand the processing of `.gitignore`.